# How to place elements in-line when they have display:block defined in style attribute

Tags: html, css

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <input name="button" type="submit" class="btn_big" value=" Add Dependent" >
        <input id="editBtn" style="display: block;" name="button" type="button" class="btn" value=" Edit " onclick="editDep();" >
        <input name="button23" type="button" class="btn" value="Back" onclick="goBack('../login/loadHome.action');"/>
 </td></tr>
      </table>


  <script>
  var searchApprovalStatus = someElement; 
  if(searchApprovalStatus != "0"){
  var elemt = document.getElementById("editBtn");
  elemt.style.display = "none";
  }
  </script>
```

But I am getting the buttons as :
[image]

If I remove the `id` & `style`, ie

```
id="editBtn" style="display: block;"
```

all three buttons come in a same line.

I can not remove this. Is it possible to still get the buttons in straight line?

Comment: Try this: `.btn_big, .btn{ float:left; }`

Comment: Try this <td align="left">

Comment: Try `id="editBtn" style="display: inline-block;"`

Comment: choz is right, you can use either `display: inline-block`, or `float: left`. But I'll recommend you to use inline-block, using float is little tricky when aligning.

Comment: here is the fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/8njpjruL/)

Comment: style="display: inline-block;" works like a charm.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to override the inline styles. To do this use the following CSS:

```
input.btn[style],
input.btn_big[style] {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/1m6xw5f2/)

```js
var searchApprovalStatus = someElement;
if (searchApprovalStatus != "0") {
  var elemt = document.getElementById("editBtn");
  elemt.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
input.btn[style],
input.btn_big[style] {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <input name="button" type="submit" class="btn_big" value=" Add Dependent">
      <input id="editBtn" style="display: block;" name="button" type="button" class="btn" value=" Edit " onclick="editDep();">
      <input name="button23" type="button" class="btn" value="Back" onclick="goBack('../login/loadHome.action');" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please.. fix your code.. because your answer is accepted means it okeay to do it like this...

Comment: Can you explain @Phil?

Comment: http://codepen.io/Andelhex/pen/jWaaPV  your css-code affected the whole document.. it is often see new user copy&paste code.. this should be avoided..

Comment: Ah, I have added a more specific selector so it doesn't effect other elements.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is inline-style you need to use `!important` to overrule it.
i used the ID selector so no other tag will be affected by this.

[Source: css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/)

> by **[Rohit Agrawal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1573309/rohit-agrawal)**
>
> However, using !important is considered a bad practice.
>
> Reason:
>
> The !important value appended to a CSS property value is an automatic
>   win. It overrides even inline styles from the markup. The only way an
>   !important value can be overridden is with another !important rule
>   declared later in the CSS with equal or great specificity value
>   otherwise.

```css
input#editBtn {
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <input name="button" type="submit" class="btn_big" value=" Add Dependent" >
        <input id="editBtn" style="display: block;" name="button" type="button" class="btn" value=" Edit " onclick="editDep();" >
        <input name="button23" type="button" class="btn" value="Back" onclick="goBack('../login/loadHome.action');"/>
 </td></tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Choz:

`style="display: inline-block;"` worked fine for me.

**Thanks again**.